# I cannot get the values posted from html in MVC

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I cannot get the posted values from html in MVC. I have 3 controls in html. One of them is DropDownList and two of them are DateTime. I can get the values of DateTimes but cannot get the DropDownList. Here is my code from html

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(M => M.AntsoftCrmUser, new SelectList(Model.AntsoftCrmUser, "Id", "Username"))
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.StartDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" }, type = "datetime-local" })
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.EndDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" }, type = "datetime-local" })
```

and this is my controller code that gets called after the html posted...

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UserTotalTimeSpentReport(int? Id,DateTime? StartDate,DateTime? EndDate) 
{
    return View();
}
```

How can get the value from DropDownList? Should I use "int? Id" or "string Username" ?

Comment: With what I am seeing just make sure that the name of the parameter is the name of the dropdown. It looks like it is Id in the parameter but on the UI it is "AntsoftCrmUser".

Comment: AntsoftCrmUser is the model name, I thought Id or Username is the name of the DropDown

Comment: @CraigSelbert, I used "object AntsoftCrmUser" and it worked. Thanks